# Can I join my account from another Steam account when I bind it to my Steam account?

Tags: steam, pc, robocraft

I have a Robocraft account that I share with one of my friends, I recently logged in and saw a function to bind the Robocraft account to my Steam Account, if I do that, will my friend be able to join my account from his account?

Comment: Assuming the game is available off-steam, all Steam does is just log you in automatically. If you run the game through off-steam launcher, it should still ask for login and password, therefore not really mattering if it's tied to your steam account or not. You won't be able to bind the game account to a different steam account though. I am 99% sure what I'm saying is right, but someone else might be able to confirm for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, that if the account can be linked to Steam, this would need to run from the same Steam, with the only difference that one has to log onto Steam, beyond that, there should be no problem; Only your amnigo would have to have your Steam account to play.

Comment: Tried today, and was able to join with my smurf. Thanks for answer btw.